# Keystore: Why does getCertificateChain(..) does not require password while getKey require password?

Tags: keystore

I'm using Java Keystore, looked through the API, but I can't figure out why does

```
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias)
```

not require a password to retrieve Certificate Chain while

```
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
```

require a password?

I've read this but don't see what a certificate doesn't require a password.  My particular certificate has both a public and a private key.  I can understand why a certificate that has a public key would not require a password.  I am not understanding why whenever I access a keystore, I am not required to enter the password as a parameter.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html

Answer (score 4):

**Superficial:** You need a password to get a privatekey value because the privatekey value is encrypted with the password to keep it private, because a privatekey is supposed to be private. You don't need a password to decrypt a certficate, even one in a privatekey *entry*, because the certificate is not encrypted, because there is no need for it to be private. Ah, you say, but **why** need not the cert be private?

**Fundamental:** The defining characterteristic and main feature of Public Key Cryptography is that the publickey always can be and usually is public, and the system (if correctly implemented and used) is still secure. Since a Certificate for a publickey has the primary purpose of *authentically* but not *confidentially* conveying the publickey, it is almost always also treated as public, although in practice a certificate sometimes contains *other* info that might be somewhat sensitive.

For example when an HTTPS client like a web browser connects to a website, the server must provide its certificate, and usually (most of) its cert chain, so that the client can authenticate the server as valid and protect the key exchange. These certs can always be seen by anyone who can see traffic on the net (including legitimate things like the routers in the path) and for most servers can be obtained by more or less any potential client even if actual web requests or transactions are not allowed. If you want people to send encrypted S/MIME email to you, you need to send them your cert(s) or publish the cert(s) somewhere any senders can access, so that can be assured of the correct encryption key to use for you. When you send signed S/MIME email similarly you need to include or publish your cert(s) so the recipient can verify your email -- unless the recipient(s) already has them in which case they were sent or published previously. These processes generally allow a lot of people other than the actually desired or needed senders and recipients, although not always exactly everybody, to see your cert(s). If you want to sign code you must similarly provide or make available your cert(s) for the recipients to use to verify the signature; especially for signing *applets* (a design case for Java) this usually makes your cert(s) visible to a very large fraction of the world.

**A certificate should never contain a privatekey.** The X.509 defined format has no place for it, and a proper CA is neither allowed nor able to include it. If you run your own nonstandard CA and define your own nonstandard extensions that violate long-established consensus practices to make yourself insecure, congratulations, you've succeeded.

What you normally have and should have is a privatekey *entry* containing a *privatekey value* which is private/encrypted *and one or more certificates* forming a chain with the first (or only) cert containing the publickey that *matches* (and during generation is actually derived from) the privatekey. That is how `java.security.KeyStore` defines a `PrivatKeyEntry`. You can get the certificate-chain, or the first cert, with no password. You need a password to access the privatekey *value* from the privatekey *entry*.

**File password:** all of the above is for a KeyStore in memory. If you write a KeyStore out to a file (with the default providers at least) it is *integrity* protected by with hash keyed by a *file* password (called the *store* password in `keytool`) which you must provide; when reading the file back in it is optional whether to supply this password to verify the integrity.